# Store cookies in Database

Tags: php, curl, cookies, amazon-dynamodb

Traditionally one would specify a cookie file/jar via

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$file);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$file);
```

Since I would like to access that cookies from multiple servers, I would like to store the cookies in a database.

Now I know I can set cookies using

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIE,$file);
```

So there is no problem in setting a cookie from the database.

The problem for me is to get the resulting cookies and mixing them with the existing ones.

There are solutions out there that parse the http headers for a `Set-Cookie:` header and return that.

By only updating the DB with the new cookies to be set, I would be losing existing cookies.

Is there a solution for that? It might be working to have a handler that connects to the DB and behaves like a file to curl or to code a cookie handler in PHP that merges new and existing cookies.

I want the cookies to be used for a long time, not just for log in to x to fetch y and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have been doing for years is collecting and saving  the cookies from the HTTP Response Header.

Then using them in subsequent HTTP Requests.

Cookies are key value pairs so by using an array the old cookies are preserved, automatically updated, and new ones added.

The first thing is to tell curl to return the HTTP response header (where cookies are)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

Then separate the response header from the HTTP response.  To do that we must first get the response header size.

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
```

Then use sub-strings to split the header from the response.

```
$head = substr($data,0,$skip);
$data = substr($data,$skip);
```

Next retrieve the cookies from the HTTP header stored in `$head`
Each cookie starts with 'Set-Cookie: '.
We use strpos() to find the position of the first occurrence of Set-Cookie: then each subsequent Set-Cookie:

$e is the end of cookie marker $s is the start of cookie marker.  A marker being the position with in the $head where each cookie is found.

Initially the end of cookie marker, `$e`, is zero, so the the position of the first occurrence of 'Set-Cookie'' is found.

```
$e = 0;  
$s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
```

We must add the length (12) of the string 'Set-Cookie: ' to $s which is set to the position of the first character 'S' in this string position by `strpos()`.  The actually cookie immediately follows the 'Set-Cookie: '

```
$s += 12;
```

The cookie is terminated by a semi-colon, so we set the $e end position marker to the position of the end of the cookie.

We start looking for the semi-colon after the $s start position marker by using $s as the start position for the `strpos()` to start searching.

```
$e = strpos($head,';',$s);
```

Now we have both the start and end position of the cookie.

Cookies are in the format of a key value pair as: key=value

So we split the cookie at the equal sign.

```
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
```

Then we store each cookie in an array.  Convert the array to json and save it as text either as a text file or in a Text field in a database record.

### Save Cookie Code

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$head = substr($data,0,$skip);
$data =  substr($data,$skip);
$e = 0;
while(true){
    $s = strpos($head,'Set-Cookie: ',$e);
    if (!$s){break;}  // no more Set-Cookie: found
    $s += 12;
    $e = strpos($head,';',$s);
    $cookie = substr($head,$s,$e-$s) ;
    $s = strpos($cookie,'=');
    $key = substr($cookie,0,$s);
    $value = substr($cookie,$s);
    $cookies[$key] = $value;
}
```

Keep in mind new cookies will be added.  Existing key values are updated or remain the same.

### Store Copy of Cookies

Convert cookies[] to json, then store in text field of a database record or text file.

```
$json = json_encode($cookies);
file_put_contents('cookieJar.jsn',$json);
```

Retrieve when needed again.

```
$json = file_get_contents('cookieJar.jsn');
$cookies = json_decode($json,true);
```

### Send cookies[] in the next request

```
$cookie = '';
foreach ($cookies as $key => $value){  // loop through array getting each key value pair
  $cookie .= "$k=$v; ";
}
rtrim($cookie,'; ');  // curl does not want the last terminating semi-colon.

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );

-
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to be working. I've got a question left: This seems to strip everything after the value so the expires, Max-Age, etc. strings get removed. Isn't that a bad thing since curl would send expired cookies or ones that are on another path?

Comment: I do not use the cookies for a long period of time so I never worried about them.   Typically the host will update a cookie before it expires.   I would not worry about sending expired cookies as long as it continues to work.  I cannot imagine someone seeing an expired cookie and reacting to it.   If it's important to you , you can use `strpos()` to get the `expired=` and save it with the cookie by adding a dimension to the cookies array.  `$cookies[$key][0] = $cookie; $cookies[$key][1] = $expires;`  If it works why is is my answer not checked?